# count() not counting genres

Tags: sql

i have this schema

lists TABLE

> id | movie_id(fk) | user_id

Movies TABLE

> id(pk) | genre1 | genre2

so i want to get the most reacurrence genres in one user's list
, i tried

```
 SELECT lists.movie_id, movies.genre1, count(movies.genre1) as counting,  movies.id
        FROM movies
        LEFT JOIN lists ON (movies.id = lists.movie_id)
        group by lists.movie_id, movies.genre1, movies.id
```

this sql query returning

> [
>   {"movie_id":100,"genre1":"Crime","counting":1,"id":100},{"movie_id":141267,"genre1":"Crime","counting":1,"id":141267},{"movie_id":207932,"genre1":"Crime","counting":1,"id":207932},{"movie_id":238636,"genre1":"Thriller","counting":1,"id":238636}
>   ]

although Crime genre is present 3 times in the array it counted it once at a time, it should be "counting" : 3 for Crime 
what did i do wrong ?

Comment: pls send table script and any dummy data insert script.

Comment: I Mohamed! I hope this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1?rq=1 Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, you weren't grouping by user_id at all:

```
SELECT lists.user_id, movies.genre1, count(movies.genre1) as counting
    FROM movies
    LEFT JOIN lists ON movies.id = lists.movie_id
    group by lists.user_id, movies.genre1
```

Answer (score 2):

It's doing this because you're grouping by everything. If you group by just "movies.genre1" you'll have:
Crime   3
Thriller 1

You mentioned in your question you want a list of each genre per user but I'm  not seeing you actually use the User column?

Comment: yeah for brevity sake i have omitted the user's part